# sundials package installation on windows

Tags: windows, cmake, msbuild, cmake-gui

I need to install the "cvode" from sundials package version 5.3.0. I was following the install guide, but there was an error.

The guide says "Back in the VS Command Window: (a) Run msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj". However, when I type the commands (start msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj) in the prompt, a message is shown saying that the word "msbuild" was not recognized

I have Visual Studio, so msbuild  had already been installed in my computer.

I don't know if the problem is in this other step, where there is an instruction to be done inside builddir:

Run cmake-gui ../solverdir
(c) Change CMAKE INSTALL PREFIX to instdir

I didn't understand step "(c)" very well , so I changed the "value" in the cmake windows to  "C:\Users\User\builddir\solverdir\sundials-5.3.0\instdir". However, " instdir" doesn't exist in this folder, because I couldn't find it in any of the folders inside builddir.

I'm new at this, so it would be a big help if anyone could help me find the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we discourage **images** which just represent the **text**. Instead, paste the text directly into the question post and format it appropriately (e.g. as a code, with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button). See also [ask].

Comment: thank you, I modified my question.